# Convert Python for -loop to PHP

Tags: php, python

**How can you convert the following code to PHP?**

```
summat = [sum(arra[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,len(arra),4)]
```

My attempt

```
$summat = array()
foreach ( range(0, $arra.length, 4) as $i) {
        $summat = array ( array_sum( array_slice( $array, $i, $i+5) ) )   // don't know how to append the sums the array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sum = array();
foreach(range(0, count($a), 4) as $i)
   $sum []= array_sum(array_slice($a, $i, 4));
```

"[]=" is an append-to-array operator

slice's second parameter is slice length, not the last index

or even simpler

```
$sum = array_map('array_sum', array_chunk($a, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

To append a value to an array, use:

```
$summat[] = array_sum(...);
```

The PHP way of doing ranges is similar to the C way:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arra); $i += 4) {
    // ...
}
```